# Rails: before_creating one model, go create a second model first

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - `User` and `Alias`, where `User` `has_many :aliases`.
When creating a `User`, it must be unique to any `Alias` that already exists.
When a `User` is created, they also get an `Alias` saved with that `User`'s name.

Here is the code for my `User.rb` model

```
validates_associated :aliases   # bring in any validations from relationship models

before_create :create_alias

def create_alias
  a = self.aliases.new
  a.alias = username
  return a.save
end
```

The `alias` model validation is `validates_uniqueness_of :alias`.

My theory is, that before I create a `User` model go create an `Alias` model and if that fails, then creating the `User` model should also fail.

However, when it fails, rails is exploding.
It's not doing the `validates_associated` properly.

How can I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: what do you mean with "rails is exploding"??? I guess you have some error

Comment: rails takes care of saving the associated objects when you save your User, you don't need that a.save (it will fail since user doesn't have an id yet, rails tries to save it and you end up in an infinite loop I think). Copy your User and Alias models

Comment: When I try to save a user that has the same alias as something in alias database I get this error: NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create --- undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0xb8404d0>

Comment: If I take out the a.save an alias does not get saved. Perhaps I need to create the alias differently? I've pretty much posted my entire models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be impossible to do in a model. At least with devise...

To fix this problem I just gave up trying and moved the config to the controller with something like this:

```
@user.aliases.build(:name => @user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference, you can use the :autosave and :validate options when you define the association so you can just remove that validates_associated and your before_create callback and let rails handle those actions

```
has_many :aliases
```

EDIT: I think the problem is that you are assigning new alias AFTER the validations! so, you have to build the new alias right when you assign the username of after validations

```
def username=(value) #custom setter for username
  aliases.build(alias: value)
  write_attribute(:username, value)
end
```

now the alias will be there before the validations and user.valid? will run the alias' valdations too when validating

Comment: I did this. It saved but didn't validate. I have duplicates of aliases in my database if a user tries to create a name of an existing alias I get undesired results.